# CSS - HTML : How to style li tags. 1 li tag then 2 directly underneath

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've had many tries trying to achieve this.
I am trying to achieve 3 li tags on two separate lines. On the first line 1 li tag and directly underneath 2 li tags on one line.

This is what i am trying to achieve:

[image]

This is what i currently have:

[image]

HTML

```
   <section id="logout">
            <nav>
                <ul id="l">

                    <li id="email"><a href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['Franchise_email']; ?></a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li class="line"><a href="Franchise-Details.php">C-Panel</a></li>
                    <li class="line"><a href="Logout.php"> | Logout </a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
```

CSS

```
section#logout{
font-family: AmsiPro-XLight;
float:right;
padding-right: 40px;
display: inline; 
margin-right: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:1em;
width: 150px;
height: 75px;
}

ul#l li{
font-family: AmsiPro-XLight;
display: inline;

}


 li.line{
 white-space:nowrap;
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: works fine in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/3d1eLnq5/)

Comment: @ChrisM that is so annoying because it is not working on my browser

Comment: Which browser?  in chrome its fine.  use the inspector to see if your styles are being overidden

Comment: safari. I can also see it perfectly in JSFiddle and i will do that thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
<ul>

    <li>First Line</li>
    <li style="float:left;display:inline;">Hi:</li>
    <li style="float:left;display:inline;">There</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set you list items to display: inline-block in order to allow them to be side-by-side, and then you reset the first li to display: block.

```
ul {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
li {
 display: inline-block;
}
li:first-child {
 display: block;
}
```